# Text over bitmap in android

Tags: android, github, android-bitmap

Text over bitmap with some functionality like text color and size change over bitmap.Please give me any suggestion to do or any github reference link

[image]

Comment: Did you try implementing it yourself? Please post the code that is not working for you. Otherwise, please look for a tutorial, StackOverflow is not a tutorial site :-)

Comment: And it's also not a code-request site.

Comment: @Kelevandos no.I am not trying yet.i didnt get basic idea to do.its not a tutorial site.Thank you.if you know any tutorial link please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done such work on one of my application.
I have shared code over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32371586/2149195)...

You have to replace TextView with ImageView used in my code.

Let me know if you stuck somewhere...

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you.But i need those add text over image like writing a text over an image including a option to change size of text and its color.

Comment: Yes, you can that as well.
by doing some of the changes in my code.
I have done with text in my app.

Comment: @RBK can we resize the text ??

Comment: use auto resize textview,... something like https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Answer (score 0):

Use SlopeTextView instead of normal text view. Try this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SlopeTextView extends TextView{
    final boolean topDown;

    public SlopeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        final int gravity = getGravity();
        if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
            setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
            topDown = false;
        }else
            topDown = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b){
        return super.setFrame(l, t, l+(b-t), t+(r-l));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){

        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
        canvas.rotate(-45,getHeight(),0);
        super.onDraw(canvas); 
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
<com.example.myviews.SlopeTextView
                    android:id="@+id/slopeTextView"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:text="Featured"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
```